# I cannot install the facebook SDK for swift

Tags: swift

I have tried to install the swift SDK several times as described (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/getting-started) step by step but when I try to connect App Delegate I always receive the warning "Use of unresolved identifier 'SDKApplicationDelegate'...". Also any other method from the imported FacebookCore seems to be unknown. 
Thanks a ton for any help
Franz
(Xcode 10.2.1, Swift 5)

Comment: Does your project build after you've imported the pod's?

Answer (score 0):

Does your project build after you've imported the pod's?

Make sure you are importing the library at the top of AppDelegate with

```
import FacebookCore
```

Comment: Yes, I can build and run the project with no warnings and I also import FacebookCore at the top of App Delegate.